# Bash: "tput initc" doesn't seem to work

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, tput

I'm working on a bash script in which I start off with some `tput initc` commands for specifying custom colours for use in the script. But when I run the script to test, it seems to just still be using `Terminal.app`'s default "Basic" theme colours. (I'm testing using a virtual machine running a fresh install of Mavericks.)

Here are the commands I'm using:

```
tput initc 0 300 300 300
tput initc 1 800 210 100
tput initc 2 650 760 380
tput initc 3 800 460 180
tput initc 4 350 530 670
tput initc 5 630 380 470
tput initc 6 470 710 760
tput initc 7 810 810 810
tput initc 8 570 570 570
tput initc 9 1000 280 200
tput initc 10 720 710 0
tput initc 11 1000 780 430
tput initc 12 530 760 1000
tput initc 13 820 820 1000
tput initc 14 440 760 830
tput initc 15 910 910 910
```

So to pick an example, this should set Yellow (3) to a kind of brownish colour, but when I then do a `tput setaf 3` and echo some text (either on separate lines or including it within an echo using the `$()` syntax) it still just prints the same default yellow.

What am I doing wrong? I've found very little along the way of documentation on `initc`—I don't even see it listed in `tput`'s man page—so I'm not sure if I'm even using it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to see the output of `tput initc 0 300 300 300 | cat -v` and the value of `$TERM`.

Comment: $TERM = "xterm-256color"

Comment: `tput initc 0 300 300 300 | cat -v` outputs the following:

^[]4;0;rgb:4C/4C/4C^[\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal.app doesn't support the control sequences you're trying to use here. You'll need to use another terminal application (such as [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com)), or use colors that are already available within the standard 256.

Comment: I don't believe that's correct, since I use custom colours in my Terminal theme. (In fact, they're the same colours I'm trying to use in my script.)

Comment: You can change the colors in a Terminal.app profile, but you can't change them at runtime using control sequences.